# Heroku Node.js cannot access static files

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

My server app creates some images in a 'static' folder when the client connects to the server. But the images cannot be accessed from the browser. A blank page shows up.

I have defined the creation of the static folder:

```
   var dir = __dirname + '/static';
if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
   fs.mkdirSync(dir);
}
```

The code is running well but the image cannot be accessed on Heroku(blank browser page). Any suggestion?

**UPDATE**
Seems the file can be written and read, but not externally, from the browser:

```
var filename = randomname(20) + ".txt";
fs.writeFile(__dirname + "/static/" + filename, "abc", function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(__dirname + "/static/" + filename);
    fs.readFile(__dirname + "/static/" + filename, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log("file exists");
        }
    });
});
```

The heroku console shows "file exists". So, fs.writefile can write the file and fs.readfile can read it. But I cannot access it from the browser.File location is printed as "/app/static/35dg234.txt"

Comment: Did you try to open this image with `fs`? Is it blank?

Comment: Are you using ExpressJS ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I am using express.  I am using socket.io to receive an image from the client and fs.writeFile to write the file to server in the static folder.  It says the file was successfully created at myapp.herokuapp.com/static/12332423whatever.jpg but `fs.readfile` returns an error as it can't find the file.